# Is it possible to make phoenix_swagger parse schemas in view modules?

Tags: elixir, swagger, documentation, phoenix-framework

PhoenixSwagger documentation says:

> Schema definitions are placed in a swagger_definitions/0 function within each controller module.

However it would be more intuitive if schemas were defined in View modules. 
So the question is is it possible to make phoenix_swagger parse view modules?

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to make phoenix_swagger parse view modules?

No, `phoenix_swagger` looks for the `swagger_definitions` function exported from the controller modules.

The alternative is to include schemas from the `swagger_info` function in the `Router` module:

```
  def swagger_info do
    %{
      info: %{
        version: "1.0",
        title: "Simple App"
      },
      definitions: %{
        "User" => UserView.user_schema(),
        "UserList" => UserView.user_index_schema(),
        "Product" => ProductView.product_schema()
      }
    }
  end
```